# Search and display result on next page using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i am working on search in codeigniter using ajax. i am passing value for search to codeigniter controller and getting result data in ajax success function on same page but i want to print result data on another page .

my code of viewpage  is below with ajax script.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" onblur="abc()"  name="searchs" >

<script>
    function abc() {
            var name = $("input[name=searchs]").val();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'search',
                data: "search="+name,
                success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                $("#res").html(data);
                window.location="star/prsearch"; 
               }
            }); }
       </script>
```

`window.location="star/prsearch" star/prsearch` is path for next page now i am redirecting on another page but there are no printed result data .

Comment: another do ajax and then redirect...

Comment: what is ajax used for?

Comment: Ajax is used to display data without page refresh, you are trying to get data on this page and then redirect the page if you want data on `star/prsearch` then you need to call the ajax on that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the action to your form where you want to Submit and Submit The form using a button and perform the ajax on the new page instead on load of the document

Comment: i don't want to click button, i want to search result onkeyup function , and display result on next page

Comment: you can submit the form without actually using a button on blur event of your input. and after submitting your form on the next page use the ajax call to get your result data.